# How to get correct icon path for 'manifest.json'?

Tags: vue.js, manifest.json

In my manifest.json, I have following codes

```
"icons": [
{
  "src": "/static/img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
  "sizes": "192x192",
  "type": "image/png"
},
{
  "src": "/static/img/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
  "sizes": "512x512",
  "type": "image/png"
}
```

When I open the browser, I got these error in my console

```
Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: http://localhost:8080/static/img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png (Resource size is not correct - typo in the Manifest?)
```

I double checked that I have the correct icons name in the folder. So icons name should not be the case. When I clicked that link, the image has shown. What could be the error?
My static folder ---
[image: static folder]

Comment: where is your `static` folder exist ? inside root folder ?

Comment: Question edited. You can see my static folder.

Comment: No answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Worth checking if your icons folder is being over-written by Apache or Nginx - https://electrictoolbox.com/apache-icons-directory/. In which case manifest.json won't exist. In which case use something other than icons for the folder name and update your header as required.